# How to fill space inside lines in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to fill space inside lines in this code.

Main parts of code:

```
struct point { float x; float y; };

point a = { 100, 100 }; 
point b = { 0, 200 }; 
point c = { 0, 0 }; 
point d = { 100, 0 }; 

void displayCB(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

    DeCasteljau();

    b.x = 200;
    c.x = 200;
    DeCasteljau();

    glFlush();
}
```

[image: heart]

How to fill this heart with red color (for example) ?

Comment: The main part of the code is in the `DeCasteljau` function that you don't include.

You'll need to draw the shape as a set of triangles rather than lines.

Comment: @PeterT DeCasteljau is famous algorithm and I didn't think that it is important to write it here, cause most of experienced programmers know about him. But thanks for idea of set of triangles. I will try that.

Comment: It doesn't matter how famous the algorithm may or may not be: it's inside that method that the gl draw calls happen. The only gl calls in the code you posted were `glClear` and `glFlush`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no flood fill if that's what you're looking for, and no way to write one since the frame buffer isn't generally read/write and you don't get to pass state between fragments.

What you'd normally do is tesselate your shape — convert from its outline to geometry that covers the internal area, then draw the geometry.

Tesselation is described by Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_clipping). Ear clipping isn't that hard to implement; monotone polygons are quite a bit more efficient but the code is more tricky. Luckily the OpenGL Utility Library (GLU) implements it for you and a free version can be found [via MESA](http://www.mesa3d.org/download.html) — they've even unbundled it from the rest of their OpenGL reimplementation. A description of how to use it is [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_tessellation.html).

EDIT: see also the comments. If you're willing to do this per-pixel you can use a triangle fan with reverse face removal disabled that increments the stencil. Assuming the shape is closed that'll cause every point inside the shape to be painted an odd number of times and every point outside the shape to be painted an even number of times (indeed, possibly zero). You can then paint any shape you know to at least cover every required pixel with a stencil test on the least significant bit to test for odd/even.

(note my original suggestion of increment/decrement and test for zero makes an assumption that your shape is simple, i.e. no holes, the edge doesn't intersect itself, essentially it assumes that a straight line segment from anywhere inside to infinity will cross the boundary exactly once; Reto's improvement applies the rule that any odd number of crossings will do)

Setup for the stencil approach will be a lot cheaper, and simpler, but the actual cost of drawing will be a lot more expensive. So it depends how often you expect your shape to change and/or whether a pixel cache is appropriate.

Comment: A simpler option to draw arbitrary filled polygons is using the stencil buffer. The red book (OpenGL Programming Guide) explains the concept in a section "Drawing Filled, Concave Polygons Using the Stencil Buffer" in the "Now That You Know" chapter.

Comment: I don't have the book to hand but presumably you'd construct triangles so that one vertex was always a fixed arbitrary location and the opposite edge was, in turn, every edge of the polygon, have front faces increment the stencil and and back faces decrement, then draw a whole screen quad set to appear only where the stencil buffer is non-zero?

Comment: That's about right. You draw a triangle fan with an arbitrary "anchor" point, and all the vertices of the polygon. Then all the fragments that were drawn an odd number of times are inside the polygon. Using the INVERT stencil function, they end up with a stencil value of 1. You can use a full screen quad, or something like a bounding box, for the rendering pass that then lights up the pixels inside the polygon.